# Sudden notification of parking sensor repair on dashboard while driving

Tags: sensor, parking

So I was driving my Vitara Brezza yesterday morning during rains. When I got my car out of the parking I had performed a reverse and worked as usual without any problems. The car hit the road before highway and since it's monsoon here there are puddles and pits everywhere across the road till the highway.

I got my car at a fuel station to fill up my tank and after driving a certain distance the notification popped up on the instrument cluster from no where and beeped for 2 to 3 times. It showed an error in rear left sensor. I took another halt after sometime to check if the car got hit any stones or debris but there wasn't a single scratch. I was wondering whether it was a false alarm but after sometime it again popped up as I hit the gas pedal above 50km/hr.

After a while the notification went away, but since then whenever I start the car or take a reverse it shows sensor repair code on the instrument cluster. I went to the service center the guy said there must be some wiring issue which might be causing the error. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: If there is an identical sensor at the rear, I would start by swapping them to see if the fault moves with the sensor.

Comment: Thanks. I am not an automotive expert so not sure how to do it. Though I am simply wondering what could have caused the issue in first place. Just to make sure the technician provides me a valid reason and doesn't charge me with a hefty sum for fixing it.

Comment: Things can just break.  It could be water getting into a connector that cause a bad connection.  It may be a faulty sensor.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it's not a major problem. Although there was not much water where I was driving through, I had an impression of disconnected wiring due to bumpy roads while driving.

Comment: Sometimes errors will keep the check engine light coming on even if the problem is resolved, you need to get the OBD code cleared and see if it comes back. If the error comes back then you have a problem still, if the error stays cleared it was probably a temporary short caused by water.